# Como criar função onde preciso passar o parâmetro dentro de um bloco de texto no R

Tags: r, funções

Eu preciso que a variável cnpj que está estre as tags `<Parameter>` seja chamada como parâmetro de uma função. Mas note que ela está dentro de um bloco de texto que eu utilizo para consumir um web service. É possível de alguma forma?

```
recebeParam <- function(cnpj) {
     Metodo <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
         <ResponseFormat>xml</ResponseFormat>
             <Command>
                 <Name>LinxSeguroVendedores</Name>
                     <Parameters>
                         <Parameter id="cnpjEmp">cnpj</Parameter>
                     </Parameters>
                 </Command>'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja ?paste, argumento collapse. Dentro da função isto deve resolver o problema.

```
Metodo <- paste('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
         <ResponseFormat>xml</ResponseFormat>
             <Command>
                 <Name>LinxSeguroVendedores</Name>
                     <Parameters>
                         <Parameter id="cnpjEmp">', cnpj, '</Parameter>
                     </Parameters>
                 </Command>', collapse = "")
```

Nota, no entanto, que como está a função não retorna qualquer valor. Para isso deverá ser

```
recebeParam <- function(cnpj) {
    Metodo <- ...etc...
              ...etc...
    Metodo
}
```

Em `R`, a última instrução de uma função é o valor que ela retorna.

Comment: Rui, muito Bom! me ajudou demais. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

A solução do Rui é correta, só que quando se analisa a maneira que se faz programação usando strings (interpolação, etc...) em pacotes maduros na linguagem R, o pacote que me parece mais utilizado é o `glue` (pelo menos nos pacotes do [tidyverse](http://tidyverse.org/)). Ele tem funcionalidades bem impressionantes dado o estado do `base-r` em termos de manipulações de string.

Utilizando o `glue` a solução para o seu problema seria:

```
library(glue)

recebeParam <- function(cnpj) {
    Metodo <- glue::glue(
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <ResponseFormat>xml</ResponseFormat>
        <Command>
        <Name>LinxSeguroVendedores</Name>
        <Parameters>
        <Parameter id="cnpjEmp">{cnpj}</Parameter>
        </Parameters>
        </Command>'
    )

    Metodo
}
```

Sugiro dar uma olhada nos casos usuais do `glue` [aqui](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue#usage), pois ele é bem poderoso.

Comment: Não conhecia, muito obrigado, parece ser muito útil.

Comment: Guilherme, tentei usar, mas acho que faltou algum detalhe para funcionar.

Comment: Vc viu as chaves ao redor do CNPJ no texto?

Comment: Sim, eu usei as chaves mas não funcionou. Vou rever e tentar novamente.